# QMoveEvent continuously emitted

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qmainwindow, qevent

I am using the same Qt program (v5.2.1) on both windows 7 and Ubuntu. In both I have a QMainWindow that overrides the event function like so:

```
bool MyMainWindow::event(QEvent *event) {
    switch(event->type()) {
    case QEvent::Move:
        // Do stuff
        break;
    }
    return QWidget::event(event);
}
```

In there I look for the `QEvent::Move` to do some processing. On windows, if I click and drag the window around the event seems to happen continuously. However, on Ubuntu it only happens after the mouse is released. I can't seem to find this in any documentation and would appreciate some clarification.

Comment: You're depending on platform-specific behavior that, as you correctly surmise, doesn't extend to Ubuntu. You need to do whatever you need to do in some other way, possibly by using mouse capture.